# Egit - merging does not work

Tags: git, merge, egit

We have a project that is being developed for a year now.
Lately our git merge functionality is acting crazy:

If i do a merge of 2 different branches (one of them is the master). I get the following merge conflict:

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< myBranch <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

.................
..................
..................

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< myBranch <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< master <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

.................
..................
..................

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< master <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

i.e. the merge is working with putting one branch code on top of the other.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got those files changed in both branches, so Git cannot just make a fast-forward merge. So it offers you to process the code manually to resolve a merge conflict. Putting code fragments from both versions in the above manner is just normal for Git.

If the whole file contents are put that way, that means that Git sees them as different. Make a `git diff master feature_branch` before merge. What differences does Git show?

A possible source of differences are newline characters. If there's a developer with badly configured **auto.crlf**, they may overwrite newlines when they push to a central repo. That actually changes every string and can result in the above situation.